# Setting java home in docker

Tags: java, tomcat, docker

I have a base ubuntu docker image and am installing java 8 on it. I need to set java home in the docker file as tomcat needs it. How do i know the location of jre installed to set java home.

Answer (score 5):

Best answer would be use docker official java image.  [Dockerfile](https://github.com/docker-library/openjdk/blob/e6e9cf8b21516ba764189916d35be57486203c95/8-jre/Dockerfile)

If you still want your own image with Java home set. Add this lines to your **Dockerfile**

```
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y openjdk-8-jdk && \
    apt-get install -y ant && \
    apt-get clean && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/ && \
    rm -rf /var/cache/oracle-jdk8-installer;

ENV JAVA_HOME /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/
RUN export JAVA_HOME
```

Comment: yes, but wanted to explore a way to do it on base linux image.

Comment: https://hub.docker.com/_/java/, go through this link will help you on different images alpine, slim and many other options too. go through all Dockerfiles, you will find the help